# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, syntax

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in StatusIG.php on line 25

I really dont see any problem in my code, why this is happening, please help. Im a beginner in PHP

my LINE 25 is >> if($status == 0)

```
    $accountdb_ip = "ip"; //Accountserver-IP
    $accountdb_login = "acc"; //Accountserver-Loginname
    $accountdb_pw = "psw"; //Accountserver-Passwort
    $db_ip = "ip"; //DB-Server-IP
    $db_login = "acc"; //DB-Server-Loginname
    $db_pw = "psw"; //DB-Server-Passwort

    $con = mysql_connect($db_ip, $db_login, $db_pw);
    $con_account = mysql_connect($accountdb_ip, $accountdb_login, $accountdb_pw);
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"], $con);

    $result_id = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player.player WHERE name='".$name."' LIMIT 1", $con);
    $player_acc_id = mysql_result($result_id, 0, "account_id");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account.account WHERE id='".$player_acc_id."'", $con);
    $status = mysql_result($result, 0, "raiguard")

    if($status == 0)
        {echo "0";}
    elseif($status == 1)
        {echo "1";}
    elseif($status == 2)
        {echo "2";}

    mysql_close($con);
    mysql_close($con_account);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the semicolon on the end of:

```
$status = mysql_result($result, 0, "raiguard")
```

Replace it with:

```
$status = mysql_result($result, 0, "raiguard");
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier for us if you posted that error here.

Comment: thanks but now different error

Notice: Undefined index: name in RaiGuardStatusIG.php on line 17
Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 4 in RaiGuardStatusIG.php on line 20
Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5 in RaiGuardStatusIG.php on line 23

line 17: $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"], $con);

line 20: $player_acc_id = mysql_result($result_id, 0, "account_id");

line 23: $status = mysql_result($result, 0, "raiguard");

Comment: @user3368877 how is produced your links to get the GET name ?

Comment: That's a local link. We can't see that.

Comment: You're using name even if it's not set. Check first and default to a blank string. `$name = ( isset( $_GET['name'] ) ) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"], $con) : '';`